# Introducing a teenager to webdesigning

Tags: language-agnostic

My eleven year brother want to be webdesigner/webmaster and I wonder how to help him with this? What books you recommend? What soft is good for start?

Maybe incomedia and photoshop?

Comment: I started to delve into HTML at his age, and all I had was Tools > View Source in IE 5. There wasn't such thing as ebooks or podcasts back then, and I made do. /oldman

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whatever training methods you decide on, just make sure he is encouraged to follow web standards as much as possible... its a lot harder throwing away the bad habits later on...

As for books I would probably recomend anything from the SitePoint series, these are really easy to use books and very useful for complete starters, they won't be as concise as the other manuals from Wrox, Apress, O'Reily but he is after all only 11!

http://www.amazon.co.uk/Build-Your-Website-Right-Using/dp/0980455278/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1273343564&sr=8-1

**Author Page and Contents:**
http://www.sitepoint.com/books/html2/

Comment: Three cheers for standards and good habits. I learned to do everything wrong by reading shoddy code and mimicking Dreamweaver output. Then, I read Zeldman's book, and started again from scratch:
http://www.amazon.com/Designing-Web-Standards-Jeffrey-Zeldman/dp/0321616952/jeffreyzeldmanprA/

Answer (score 2):

[Head First HTML](http://headfirstlabs.com/books/hfhtml/) is a good introduction to good HTML and CSS. 11 though might be a touch young for it.

Comment: Keeping in mind he is 11, I think that book is a little long but that's not to say he couldn't use it as a reference.

Answer (score 1):

Just about anyone with any sort of technical skills can learn HTML. Just have him start working on a website and give him the basic template. He'll figure out the rest. I started when I was 11 and it wasn't that difficult.

He might not be doing everything correctly but that can be fixed with time and practice.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure he learns complete basics and start with small web to make a big out of it try him to apply new idea into the designing
W3c school for basics  and try to invent more through it.